# How to select multiple files in Github for Mac GUI

Tags: macos, github

I have about 200 changed files in my project that I would like to Git to ignore and 100 changed files that I would like to commit. I am having to ignore them one by one (ie, right click on file->ignore)-- this is very painful due to the number of files involved.

The changed files are all in a list under the 'Changes' tab, and I would like to group select all of them and ignore. Is there any way I can select multiple files in Github for mac? It seems like it should be really easy, but holding shift, control, open apple, dragging, etc all do not allow me to select more than one file at a time-- it's incredibly frustrating.

The checkboxes and 'select all checkbox' only apply to commits, ignore cannot be applied to selected checkboxes. Also, I cannot use 'select all' because the bottom third of the files are meant for committing.

I could do the ignore via command line, but is the GUI client useless for such things?
Any advice on how to use the GUI thing would be much appreciated! :)

Here is a screenshot of the 'Changes' tab-- just imagine that list of files extending all the way down.
http://www.mikesoltys.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Screen-Shot-2012-03-07-at-12.37.38-PM-1024x595.png

Comment: so this is more of a public feature request instead of a suggestion e-mailed to the developers of the Mac client?

Comment: I'm genuinely asking for help with how to use the GUI client here-- it 's a very basic action (ie, selecting multiple files) so it seems as if it should be possible to do already without requesting any new features. However, I have no idea how I can do this, so I thought I'd ask on SO.
All answers to similar questions skip the GUI and refer directly to the command line, but for workflow purposes I'd really like to know how to do it using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to select multiple files, according to the [GitHub support articles](https://help.github.com/categories/31/articles). However, if the files you want to ignore have a common pattern in their filenames and/or directory names, you can use a [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.